# React/GraphQL/Neo4J: GraphQL Error

Tags: reactjs, neo4j, graphql, react-apollo, graphql-js

I am using the https://grandstack.io/ for a project.  Currently, I am trying to get results return in a JSON form of nodes and links. The following link, [Drawing a graph using d3js from neo4j/cypher json output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27348061/drawing-a-graph-using-d3js-from-neo4j-cypher-json-output), was helpful but now I am receiving the following GraphQL Error:

> [GraphQL error]: Message: Failed to invoke function
>   apoc.cypher.runFirstColumn: Caused by:
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.frontend.v3_3.InternalException: Expected to
>   find a node at this but found Map

In my schema file this is what I have:

```
Type Query {action(startTime: Float!, endTime: Float!): [action] @cypher(statement: "MATCH path = (sec:Second)<-[:AT_TIME]-(act:action)-[:TARGET]->(obj:object) WHERE act.timestamp >= startTime AND act.timestamp <= endTime unwind map(path) as no UNWIND rels(path) as r RETURN {nodes: collect(distinct no), links: collect(DISTINCT {source:id(startNode(r)),target:id(endNode(r))})}
```

Comment: This is one of the entries in the array from the response: Map{links -> List{Map{source -> Long(998299), target -> Long(995325)}...

Comment: I found out that this query does not return a list of Relationships, rather, it returned a list of Paths.

Comment: Can you share your type definition for the `action` type in your GraphQL schema?

Comment: `type action {
  action: String!
  startTime: Float!
  endTime: Float!
  timestamp: Float!
  Second: [Second] @cypher(statement: "MATCH (sec:Second)<-[:AT_TIME]-(this)-[:TARGET]->(obj:object) RETURN sec")
  object: [object] @cypher(statement: "MATCH (sec:Second)<-[:AT_TIME]-(this)-[:TARGET]->(obj:object) RETURN obj")
 }`

Comment: My goal is to slip the data up into nodes and links to use in a D3 directional graph.